# Disable download MP4 from website

Tags: php, jwplayer

I have a website for playing MP4 and M3U files, and i have JWplayer for play this content on this website,

I want that only JWplayer be able to have access to file, and be able to play it, and I want to deny other access to this contents, I mean I want disable users access and i want they was not be able to download from my page, how should i do it ?

Comment: Not possible. By definition, for a media file to be playable, it **HAS** to be downloaded to the client's system. And it is literally impossible to 100% reliably tell the difference between "download for playing" and "download for saving to disk". One way or another, the bytes in the file have to go over the wire to the client's system.

Comment: If it's possible to send files through cURL requests, then create a router and get the file through that. Then store videos outside the root path. So your accessing a middle man to get the file, maybe then it can't be downloaded

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting token signing in place which will make it harder to have your content stolen (but not impossible): https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1433647-url-token-signing

Otherwise, you may want to try using a more secure streaming method like HLS or DASH.

Answer (score 0):

[RTMP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-Time_Messaging_Protocol)

OR

[hls](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming)

The only solution that i know.

Basicly when client play your video, it downloaded as browser cache.